# How to calculate percentage of a sales column grouped by city name

Tags: r

I am new to R and need help in writing a code. I have a data frame with below variables

```
Name  city_name   Sales
Cust1  Delhi       1000
Cust2  Gujrat      4565
Cust3  Mumbai      2658
Cust4  Pune        9200
Cust5  Delhi       4565
Cust6  Gujrat      1900
Cust7  Mumbai      1551
Cust8  Pune        2000
```

I want to Calculate percentage of sales by each city. How do I do that in R.

For example. The data should look like:

```
city_name  %Sales
Delhi      40%
Mumbai     20%
Pune       15%   
Gujrat     25%
```

Comment: `prop.table(aggregate(Sales ~ city_name, df, sum)$Sales)`

Comment: Couldn't have said it better (or faster) myself.

Comment: `aggregate(Sales ~ city_name, data = df1, FUN = function(x) 100*sum(x)/sum(df1$Sales))`